# The links between the nodes in Force-Directed Graph in D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I am working on a graph which basically contains at least 150 nodes using D3 Javascript. The idea can be described as follows:

One node is connected to 100 nodes. 
49 nodes of these 100 nodes are connected to other 49 nodes.

Let's clarify it. I know 100 people. 49 people of them have birthdays. Each of which represents a node.

In such a way, I could manage to link them together using `source` and `target` through some arrays in Javascript. I think I am missing something very important to understand in Force-Directed Graph in D3. As far as I am aware, the links can be implemented with `source` and `target`. My problem is I cant understand how I can link these links to these nodes. I do not know on what basis I can create an array to hold my name, peoples' names and their birthdays so they can be linked together. In my graph, it gives me the right person but the wrong birthday. Could anyone please guide me the right way how to do with this matter. I am following this tutorial: and could not understand how I can create an array to add the information such as: name, peoples names and birthday.

> http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid you will need to post what you have tried so far on `jsfiddle` or some other place with some mock data for us to be able to guide you.

Comment: The problem is I have a big amount of data. I will try to manage to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the nodes and links are linked is by index. That is, if `target: 0`, it means that the target node of that link is the first one in the list of nodes, as passed to the force layout. You can add any data you need to both links and nodes -- for links, the nodes are also available through `link.source` and `link.target`.

Alternatively, you can specify the source and target of a link as the object itself -- this is actually what D3 does internally when you pass the links to the force layout. As it can't work with  the indices as such, they are replaced with the resolved node objects (this is why you can access the actual objects through the links).

If you're specifying the graph structure through external data (e.g. JSON), then you should use indices to identify nodes in links. If you're generating the data structure in Javascript, you could use references to the actual objects instead.

Comment: Lars. Your answers are always helpful. Actually I am retrieving data from JSON file and put them in arrays. After that, I will apply what you explained in the very beginning of your answer. In the meantime, I would be extremely grateful if you could possibly read through my codes. I will try to send you a little sample of my codes. In this case, do you think that source and target can be defined by the indices of the array that I am storing the nodes in?!

Comment: The answer to your question is almost certainly yes, but I should be able to answer more definitively once I've seen your code.

Comment: How can I show you my code? Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: If you don't want to post it here, you can send me an email.

Comment: I will do this. Thank you very much indeed, Lars for your support. I will follow your answer at the moment hopefully I will get some results and then email you the files.