# Nodes and links in Collapsible Force Layout in D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am new to D3 Javascript and currently following some tutorials to understand how it works. I have looked through the codes in this link: > http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130 for `Collapsible Force Layout` I have tried to figure out how nodes and links are connecting. Unfortunately, I could not fully understand on what basis the nodes are connected to each other. However, I have understood how these nods are connected in the Force-Directed Graph > [The links between the nodes in Force-Directed Graph in D3 Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130287/the-links-between-the-nodes-in-force-directed-graph-in-d3-javascript) , I could not really understand how the links in Collapsible Force Layout is working. How are the `id` and `target` working? Is is based on the array index? Could anyone please explain to me how they are working? Your assistance would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links in the collapsible force layout example are based on parent-child relationships. That is, each node is connected to the nodes listed under `.children`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Each node is connected to the nodes listed under .children. OK. Is every node connected to its children with the id that is provided in the code? What I learned from you before that in Force-Directed Graph, there were a source and target. I could not figure out the source and target in collapsible force layout. May you kindly explain to me a little more? Thank you.

Comment: The structure that contains `.source` and `.target` is in this case produced by the call to `d3.layout.tree().links(nodes)`.

Comment: Lars, I beg you to be patient with me just for a few minutes, please. Before getting the source and target produced by d3.layout.tree().links(nodes), how did the code let the tree layout know that this is the node and these are its children? I have noticed: d.target.id. Is that involved?!

Comment: No, the target ID doesn't have anything to do with it. Have a look at [the documentation for the tree layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout). It knows which nodes are the children of which node in the way that I have described -- by looking at `.children` for each node.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, Lars. May you please tell me what the target ID is for?

Comment: This is just used later in the code to match data to DOM elements. It has nothing to do with figuring out which nodes are connected.

Comment: I have created Force Directed Graph and would like to apply the onClick method which is in Collapsible Force Layout. Do you think it is possible to do similar idea of clicking nodes in Force Directed Graph?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- you would need to have some kind of hierarchical structure (like `.children()`) to make any layout collapsible.